# MongoDB: Should I use Solid State Devices?

Tags: mongodb

I am pretty new to MongoDB. Going through MongoDB's online documentation ([here](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/write-performance/#hardware)), I came across the following statement:

> Solid state drives (SSDs) can outperform spinning hard disks (HDDs) by
>   100 times or more for random workloads

Does this mean that it is recommended that mongo-db should runs on SSDs in production for best performance (from a hardware perspective)? We working on improving mongo-db performance for our product in production.

Comment: Most of the time better hardware always improves performance. The problem is, do you really need them? Usually I would recommend a RAID10 rather than SSD. But that depends on your use case. A bit more info about your project would be helpful.

Answer (score 2):

Before working on improving performance, it is nice to find your bottleneck. You can buy the fastest drive possible and it would do nothing, because the problem would be in your RAM or your queries. So before checking which type of disk you have to buy, better check where exactly is your problem.

I would start with analysing your queries with [explain](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/cursor.explain/), checking your indexes. If your problem is not in reads, but in writes, check if your documents were moved too many times (moves are expensive so you have to investigate why they happened). You can check them with `db.system.profile.find({'op': 'update', 'moved': True})`. Then try to see if [padding](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/record-padding/) can help you to mitigate the moves. If no, than may be a good idea can be to restructure your database.

But if you want to look into hardware, take a look at [this](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/administration/production-notes/) and mongodb [video](http://youtu.be/BYegVYF7lHY) about hardware.

Comment: [mongostat](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/program/mongostat/) and [mongotop](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/program/mongotop/) are also very useful tools to analyse your bottleneck.

Comment: @yaoxing you are absolutely correct. These are useful tools to find bottleneck. My main motif in the answer is that the most important is to find a bottleneck and only after that decide what to do with it.

Comment: Yes, I totally agree with you. I'm just providing some extra information for @Amit Sharma to reference ;)